# What needs to be corrected to have R function run in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to get the following simple R function running in `Shiny`. 
It works fine in `R`.

```
LifeExpectancy <- function(Age){
    X <- which(lifeExpCH$Alter == Age)
    LifeE <- lifeExpCH$`2018`[X:100]
    Y <- seq(Age, 99, 1)
    df1 <- data.frame(LifeE, Y)
    ggplot(df1, aes(Y, LifeE)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = “Age”, y = “Years Expected to Live”, title = “Life Expectancy Switzerland 2018”)
    }
```

What I wrote in `Shiny` and is not working.

Would very be very happy for some help, thank you.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
             numericInput(inputId = "Age", label = "Enter your age", value = 30, min = 0, max = 99)
         ),
        mainPanel(
             plotOutput(outputID = "LifeExp_plot")
         )
     )
 )
     LifeExpectancy <- function(Age){
     X <- which(lifeExpCH$Alter == Age)
     LifeE <- lifeExpCH$`2018`[X:100]
     Y <- seq(Age, 99, 1)
     df1 <- data.frame(LifeE, Y)
     return(df1)
 }
 server <- function(input, output){
     LifeExpectancy <- reactive ({
         LifeExpectancy(input$Age)
     })
     output$LifeExp_plot <- renderPlot({
         ggplot(LifeExpectancy, aes(Y, LifeE) ) +
geom_line()     
     })  
 }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You need to put `LifeExpectancy(input$Age)` in the renderPlot and get rid of the reactive({}) bit. Also the LifeExcpectancy function can't be defined in the ui, put it somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your answer. I placed the LifeExpectancy function outside of the ui.  Got rid of the reactive({}) bit as advised. See below:  

`server <- function(input, output){
    output$LifeExp_plot <- renderPlot({
        LifeExpectancy(input$Age)
        ggplot(LifeExpectancy, aes(Y, LifeE) ) +
            geom_line()
    })
}`


==> but not working as wished.

Comment: A few things: Would use different function names `LifeExpectancy` is a function with age as argument and also a `reactive` function; in addition, `plotOutput` should have `outputId` (small 'd'); also, when you call your `reactive` LifeExpectancy` function, use parentheses: `ggplot(LifeExpectancy(), aes(Y, LifeE))...`

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you, will continue getting it right hopefully:) Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Martin - I hope this may be helpful. I am not able to run as I don't have `lifeExpCH` available.

Note I renamed your calculation function as `LifeExpectancyFromAge` to distinguish from your `reactive` function. And when you call your `reactive` function, make sure to use parentheses.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

LifeExpectancyFromAge <- function(Age){
  X <- which(lifeExpCH$Alter == Age)
  LifeE <- lifeExpCH$`2018`[X:100]
  Y <- seq(Age, 99, 1)
  df1 <- data.frame(LifeE, Y)
  return(df1)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "Age", label = "Enter your age", value = 30, min = 0, max = 99)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "LifeExp_plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  LifeExpectancy <- reactive ({
    LifeExpectancyFromAge(input$Age)
  })
  output$LifeExp_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(LifeExpectancy(), aes(Y, LifeE)) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(x = "Age", y = "Years Expected to Live", title = "Life Expectancy Switzerland 2018")
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @ Ben, thank you very much, it worked! Really appreciate your help. This will help me greatly in the future. Thank you. Kind regards